# Is a group structure required for randomization tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test, randomized-tests

In randomization tests (for example in Testing Statistical Hypothesis Theorem 15.2.1 Lehmann and Romano) it is required that we have a group of transformations $\mathbf{G}$ on which $X$ and $gX$ have the same distribution for all $g \in \mathbf{G}$ under the null.

For a given test statistic T, we compute all values of $T(gX)$ for all $g \in \mathbf{G}$ and form critical values by looking at quantiles of the $T(gX)$'s. We reject the null hypothesis if the $T(X)$ is larger than the $1-\alpha$-quantile.

Is it necessary that $\mathbf{G}$ is a group (in the algebra sense)? In particular, the proof in Lehmann and Romano does not seem to require that any properties of a group, only that the distribution does not change under $g$.

Comment: It would help to give a clear account of just what kind of "randomization test" you are contemplating and what assumptions are made, otherwise you have limited your audience to those who are familiar with this reference, which might be much smaller than the set of people who can answer the question.

Comment: Thank you.  Because I suspect the answer depends on the null hypothesis, could you quote precisely what the null hypothesis given by Lehmann and Romano is?

Comment: @whuber I believe there is no specific null hypothesis, only that under the null we have symmetry under $\mathbf{G}$. The theorem in Lehmann and Romano is that we have size control under the stated conditions (nothing about the power, which would require that symmetry be violated under the alternative.)

Comment: There you go: if the null hypothesis is $G$-symmetry, then *a fortiori* $G$ is a group.  If you were to change the null hypothesis to invariance under some other set of transformations, such as a semi-group, then $G$ would only need to be a semi-group, *etc.*